# Not able to retrieve data from DB second time in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created an app that can save contacts from text box to database. Contacts would be number entered or from default contacts. This app has about 5 edit text.

The problem over here is: The first time when I enter the number and click save button the number is getting saved and also gets retrieved properly. When I do the same the second time  for a new number. The number is getting saved. When I try to retrieve the numbers from DB I can't see the number.

I am using getter and setter methods for storing the transaction values.

Below is what I have tried and getting the problem:

From edittext to database via getters and setters method.

```
         Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
      //arrsendcontactsinverse is the arraylist which stores all the numbers

         contacts.setArrcontactsofbean(arrsendcontactsinverse);
         database.addContacts(contacts);
```

//to retrieve the data i am using the code below.

```
db = new DataBase(this);

    if(db.getContactsCount()>0)
    {
        Contacts contactFromDb = db.getContacts();

        contact1.setText(contactFromDb.getArrcontactsofbean().get(0));
        contact2.setText(contactFromDb.getArrcontactsofbean().get(1));
        contact3.setText(contactFromDb.getArrcontactsofbean().get(2));
        contact4.setText(contactFromDb.getArrcontactsofbean().get(3));
        contact5.setText(contactFromDb.getArrcontactsofbean().get(4));
    }
}
```

This is the code in the DataBase.java.

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "ContactsTable";
private static final String KEY_CONTACT1 = "contact1";  //column name
private static final String KEY_CONTACT2 = "contact2";  //column name
private static final String KEY_CONTACT3 = "contact3";  //column name
private static final String KEY_CONTACT4 = "contact4";  //column name
private static final String KEY_CONTACT5 = "contact5";  //column name

ArrayList<String> arrcontactofdatabasehandler= new ArrayList<String>();

public Databasehandler(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS +"("
            +KEY_CONTACT1+ " TEXT," 
            +KEY_CONTACT2+ " TEXT,"
            +KEY_CONTACT3+ " TEXT,"
            +KEY_CONTACT4+ " TEXT,"
            +KEY_CONTACT5+ " TEXT,"
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Adding new contact
void addContacts(Contacts contacts)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_CONTACT1,contacts.getArrcontactsofbean().get(0));
    values.put(KEY_CONTACT2,contacts.getArrcontactsofbean().get(1));
    values.put(KEY_CONTACT3,contacts.getArrcontactsofbean().get(2));
    values.put(KEY_CONTACT4,contacts.getArrcontactsofbean().get(3));
    values.put(KEY_CONTACT5,contacts.getArrcontactsofbean().get(4));

        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

// Getting contacts
Contacts getContacts()
{
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Contacts contacts = new Contacts();

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        do 
        {
            arrcontactofdatabasehandler.add(cursor.getString(0));       
            arrcontactofdatabasehandler.add(cursor.getString(1));   
            arrcontactofdatabasehandler.add(cursor.getString(2));   
            arrcontactofdatabasehandler.add(cursor.getString(3));   
            arrcontactofdatabasehandler.add(cursor.getString(4));       

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    contacts.setArrcontactsofbean(arrcontactofdatabasehandler);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return contacts;
}

public int getContactsCount() 
{
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    // return count
    db.close();
            return count;
}

public void dropTable()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS +"("
            +KEY_CONTACT1+ " TEXT," 
            +KEY_CONTACT2+ " TEXT,"
            +KEY_CONTACT3+ " TEXT,"
            +KEY_CONTACT4+ " TEXT,"
            +KEY_CONTACT5+ " TEXT,"
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    db.close();
}

  }
```

Contacts.java.(these are the getter and setter methods )

```
 public class Contacts 
{
    ArrayList<String> arrcontactsofbean= new ArrayList<String>();

public Contacts()
{

}

public ArrayList<String> getArrcontactsofbean() 
{   
    return arrcontactsofbean;
}

public void setArrcontactsofbean(ArrayList<String> arrcontactsofbean)
{
    this.arrcontactsofbean = arrcontactsofbean;
}
}
```

I couldn't find out the exact problem here.

Comment: post the whole class. where is your insert method?

Comment: I have done it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you place the code where you are retrieving the contacts from contacts object?

Comment: where you can't see the number?

Comment: its not getting retrieved in getContacts() of DataBase.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my understanding is concerned. I think the problem is in the getContacts Method:

According to your logic one object of Contacts method will contain five contacts, and so as it is getting saved in the DB.

But you are not retreiving them in the right way so will have to create an array of the class Contacts and then each individual row will contain Five contacts (Which reflects the number of columns)

So do something like this:

```
   // Getting contacts
   Contacts[] getContacts()
   {
       String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
       int count = getContactsCount();

       **//here can you check if the count is greater than 0**
       Log.d("Database", "Count: " + count);

       Contacts contacts[] = new Contacts[count];



       int index = 0;
       // looping through all rows and adding to list
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
       {
           do 
           {
               Log.d("Database", "Initializing contacts...");
               contacts[index] = new Contacts(); ///initialize contacts here 
               ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
               arr.add(cursor.getString(0));       
               arr.add(cursor.getString(1));   
               arr.add(cursor.getString(2));   
               arr.add(cursor.getString(3));   
               arr.add(cursor.getString(4));       
               contacts[index].setArrcontactsofbean(arr);
               index++;

           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }

       cursor.close();
       db.close();
       return contacts;
   }
```

You will have to change the way you are retreiving results in your code i.e. deal with Array and then show up.

*"I tried retrieving the value using the arraylist method as u said, and it gave me a null pointer exception." ?*

**Try below code to traverse the results:**

```
 Contacts contactsFromDb[];
 contactsFromDB = db.getContacts() /// Note the db is the object of Database class in which the getContacts() method is

 if(contactsDB != null){
    for(int k =0; k < contactsFromDB.length; k++){
    arrforcontactsdb = contactsFromDB[k].getArrcontactsofbean();

    for(int i = 0 ;i < (arrforcontactsdb.size());i++)   //not it should not be -1
    { 
        Log.e("retrieved VALUES ARE",""+arrforcontactsdb.get(i));
    }
```

*" and can you let me know why are you using arraylist of array in database.java.?"*

**Answer:**

It is not ArrayList of Array....It is the ArrayList of String containing each individual contact. The Reason why it is an array because each row will contain 5 contacts Representing one Contacts object so multiple rows means multiple objects hence I stored them in Array while retreiving.

Comment: I tried retrieving the value using the arraylist method as u said, and it gave me a null pointer exception.Contacts contactFromDb = new Contacts();
   
   arrforcontactsdb = contactFromDb.getArrcontactsofbean();

   for(int i = 0 ;i < (arrforcontactsdb.size()-1);i++)
   {   
   Log.e("retrieved VALUES ARE",""+arrforcontactsdb.get(i));
   }, and can you let me know why are you using arraylist of array in database.java.?

Comment: Thanks. I will check it and come back.

Comment: Hi, i tried the above code, but its throwing a nullpointerexception at the below line.arrforcontactsdb = contactsFromDb[k].getArrcontactsofbean();

Comment: I have placed a logging statement in the getContacts() Please run your app and see if this logging statement gets printed.

Comment: Hi, i am not getting the logs which you have placed in the getcontacts() .I am getting a nullpointerexception at the following line while traversing the values. arrforcontactsdb = contactsFromDb[k].getArrcontactsofbean();

Comment: But if you see the getContacts() method is called before the line on which you are getting nullpointer. So if you can update with your logcat output. I will be able to look why is it appearing.

Comment: Hi, please check out the the link  http://txtup.co/9x78z for logcats.I have logged in various places of control flow.I figured out that its not getting inside the if (cursor.moveToFirst()) of getContacts() method.

Comment: That is because the data is not being pulled out from database, either there is no data or data is not being inserted properly. Did you called the addContacts() method before executing the getContacts method? You must save at least save one record (5 contacts) before calling getContacts. I have also placed a logging in to print count (Edited my answer) can you please check and see whats going on

Comment: Hi, 1)Log during adding contacts http://txtup.co/NaKgj. 2) Log during getting contacts http://txtup.co/NBvvB .

Comment: Have you exactly copied the getContacts method in my answer? emphasizing on the line contacts[index].setArrcontactsofbean(arr); .Can you share the code as in eclipse project I will have go and let you know where the problem is coming from...

Comment: Hi,i fixed the issue rebuilding the code.But,Thanks for all your help.